# Hunter 99123 remote control dimming feature stopped working

Tags: lighting

It has 3 led bulbs. Used to dim just fine by holding the power on light button to dim/brighten. Light works fine still, but now only very bright and can't dim.

[I use this Hunter model 99123 remote(from Amazon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EWTLL62)

Comment: When it used to dim fine, did it have different bulbs in it?  It might not work with those LEDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an [Amazon Review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R187IR8A3GZQN3?ref=pf_vv_at_pdctrvw_srp) that might solve your problem.  The important part is towards the end of the review:

> My guess was that having the CFL bulbs installed when the remote receiver initially powered up caused it to automatically disable the dimmer feature, as explained in the instructions. I suspected this meant some manual operation was needed to restore that feature after replacing the CFLs, but the instructions and Hunter website were both mute on the subject.
>
> Then I remembered a section in the instructions that explained how to deal with "flashing CFL bulbs", and that mine flashed when first powered up. The instructions said to use the remote to turn the lights off, then on, then hold down the "fan off" button while pressing and releasing the light button twice. I wondered if this might be the "dimmer reset" feature I was looking for, so I tried it. No joy, but the instructions said to do this repeatedly until the CFL flashing stopped so I tried it again. Viola! The dimmer suddenly worked.
>
> If you have the same problem, don't waste your time with the Hunter support zombies, their inadequate instructions or website. Just do this instead.

This review comes from the [Amazon Product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EWTLL62) that the OP linked, and was from user "Sapient Hetero".  It is currently the "top ranked" review, but that could obviously change.

Also, it's possible that the dimmer wasn't made to support LED lights or support the particular lights you have installed even if it does support other LED lighs.

Comment: JPhi1618, you are right as rain. As per your instructions, I did your reset 3 times, 3rd time was the charm. Thank you for your rapid response too. You da man!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's broken. You can still use as a regular switch (on/off) but if you want the dimmer feature then you need to replace it. It might still be under warranty and if so you might be able to get it replaced for free. If you bought it from Amazon (per your link) then they might replaced it.

Comment: JPhi1618 and I posted at the same time. Hopefully his information works to correct it

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this link from Hunter website:

https://support.hunterfan.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042089334-How-do-I-toggle-the-diming-feature-

I had a similar issue, then turned out it somehow was taken out of dimming mode. Personally, I had to hold down the up and down arrows on my remote to turn it back on and then it worked as should when holding down the light button.

Comment: Can you summarize the contents of the link?